# Clang 3.3 and C++14 support?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, c++14

Clang 3.3 supports some C++14 features, like member initializers and aggregates. However, I am unable to compile this code even with `-std=c++11` switch.

```
struct A
{
   struct X { int a, b; };
   X x = { 1, 2 };
   int n;
};

A a = {{10}, 5};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me with `-std=c++11` in clang **3.2** and gcc 4.7.

Comment: In-class member initializers are a C++11 feature, no?

Comment: I do ''A a = {{10}, 5};'' and it fails. I want to use this feature of C++14.

Comment: @TonyPerez: Please edit the question to show this.

Comment: I thought the C++14 tag was forbidden from use on questions until the Standard was actually ratified.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177625/c14-or-c1y

Comment: @JohnDibling http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186994/157577

Comment: In this case, the `c++14` vs `c++1y` tag mistake paralleled the problem with compiling the code...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Post-C++11 language features in `Clang 3.3` are enabled with this command-line switch:

> -std=c++1y

Check out the bottom of this page http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html for the list of currently supported post-C++11 features in `Clang 3.3`.

Also, here you will find discussions on the upcoming `C++14` and usage examples: http://www.meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/a-look-at-cpp14-papers-part-1.html

Comment: What c++14 feature is this example using?

Comment: @balki: aggregate initialization: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3605.html